# rails session values disapear after current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

rails version is 5.0.4

To simplify the question, I will use an example which I had tested on my website.

I saved some values in session in http://myhome/a

http://myhome/a only had 2 lines code.

```
session[:asdf] = 1
render plain: "#{session.to_hash}"
```

The string I got is `{"session_id"=>"9913d09d270a4dd67c8782836d1aaaaa", "asdf"=>1}`

After that, I turn to http://myhome/b instantly

```
render plain: "#{session.to_hash}"
```

The value I got is only `{}`. I cannot even got session_id from it!!

**myhome** is fully copied from **myhome_old**

I had change the production value in secrets.yml

The same code worked find on **myhome_old**. Therefore, I think that might not be the problem of setting of my browser.

Is there something would effect the mechanism of session of rails?

Comment: If you remove `session[:asdf] = 1`, do you get `session_id` back?

Comment: No, If I remove it, I will got {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem by deleting config/initializers/session_store.rb.

It works fine now.